# UITableViewController does not show info after adding

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm tried to find solution on my own, but...so, to be short:

After adding information (in this case - String and Date type's) to the AddTaskViewController and press "Save" button the TableViewController is appears without any information. But, ViewController passed the information to a TableViewController (moreover, the notification is working). I "reload" app in simulator and all information appears!

I tried using the method 'tableView.reloadData()' in 'viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)' but it didn't help. It appears every time when i add a new task via the ViewController.

I'm sorry, I'm beginner and would appreciate any help!

class AddTaskViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var titleTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var descriptionTextView: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var notificationPicker: UIDatePicker!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    notificationPicker.maximumDate = Date()
    
}

@IBAction func saveTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    print("Save button pressed!")
    
    let titleText = titleTextField.text ?? ""
    let descriptionText = descriptionTextView.text ?? " "
    let notification = notificationPicker.date

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let newTask = Task(context: context)
    newTask.titleText = titleText
    newTask.descriptionText = descriptionText
    newTask.notification = notification
    
    if let uniqueId = newTask.taskId {
        print("TaskID: \(uniqueId)")
    }
    
    do {
        try context.save()
        let message = "Time for \(titleText)"
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.body = message
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
        
        //
        var dateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.minute, .hour, .day], from: notification)
        // dateComponents.hour =
        
        
        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)
        if let identifier = newTask.taskId {
            let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)
            let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
            center.add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
        }
    } catch let error {
        print("Error \(error)")
    }
    
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    
}

@IBAction func cancelTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

}

class StorageTableViewController: UITableViewController {

```
var tasks = [Task]()

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let fetchRequest = Task.fetchRequest() as NSFetchRequest<Task>
    
    do {
        tasks = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
    } catch let error {
        print("Error: \(error)")
    }
    
          
    tableView.reloadData()
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    
    return tasks.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "taskCellIdentifier", for: indexPath)
    let task = tasks[indexPath.row]
    
    let titleText = task.titleText ?? ""
    let descriptionText = task.descriptionText ?? " "
    cell.textLabel?.text = titleText + "" + descriptionText

    if let date = task.notification as Date? {
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    } else {
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = " "
    }
    // Configure the cell...

    return cell
}

// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return true
}
    
// Override to support editing the table view.
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if tasks.count > indexPath.row {
        let task = tasks[indexPath.row]
        // Deleting notification:
        if let identifier = task.taskId {
            let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
            center.removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: [identifier])
        }
        //
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        context.delete(task)
        tasks.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch let error {
            print("Error \(error)")
        }
        
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    }
```

Comment: Please add your code to the question, specifically how you save information, how the table view controller gets the new information, and how you implement your datasource methods.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I inserted full code

Comment: You're depending on `viewWillAppear` to update your data.  Can you add a `print` to verify it's being called after the `dismiss`?

Comment: You mean add `print` to `viewWillAppear` - right? I tried, the message was printed in Debug area...

Answer (score 0):

So, after spending a lot of time with documentation and tutorials, I decided to use my first solution - **it may not be correct, but it works (for now) :)**

I just told `AddTaskViewController` to send data to `StorageTableViewController` every time the `saveTapped` called...need a few lines for each controller to create a two way communication:

For "AddTaskViewController"

```
protocol AddTaskDelegate {
func addTaskViewController(_ addTaskViewController: AddTaskViewController, didAddTask task: Task) }


var delegate: AddTaskDelegate?
```

Then (in "saveTapped")

```
delegate?.addTaskViewController(self, didAddTask task: newTask)
```

For "StorageTableViewController" (+ add conformation to new protocol "AddTaskDelegate")

```
func addTaskViewController(_ addTaskViewController: AddTaskViewController, didAddTask task: Task) {
    
    tasks.append(task)
    tableView.reloadData()
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    
    let navigationController = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
    let addTaskViewController = navigationController.topViewController as! AddTaskViewController
    addTaskViewController.delegate = self
}
```

I think I'll find proper solution, but later...

Answer (score 0):

There’s a lot to unpack here. - Your main issue appears to be because when return to your `StorageTableViewController`, that the tasks are not being updated. I believe this is because `viewWillAppear` doesn’t get called when a view on top of it is dismissed.

It also looks like you solved the problem! But some other things you could also look into include an unwind segue, and using NSFetchedResultsController as your table view data source.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I think, yes and no, 'viewWillAppear' is called, but with old data. I guess (and not only I), in this case the problem is in queue. 'tableView' called 'tableView.reloadData()' before 'fetchRequest' - why this happened, I don't know yet. I thinking about 'managedObjectContext.performAndWait()' but it didn't help me. (I just need more experience and knowledge). I used several different approaches, but first and simplest one helped me. I'll definitely come back for this. But later!